# How to use Apollo Android from Kotlin, but without Android?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, apollo-android

I want to use Apollo Android to query the GitHub GraphQL api, using Kotlin with the Gradle Kotlin DSL but *not* on Android.

**Error message**

I do run into a specific problem, but that's probably because there is something wrong in my setup elsewhere.

To summarize, I have a `ViewLogin.graphql` file, from which a `ViewLoginQuery` is generated, but when I try to use `ViewLoginQuery.builder()` then `unresolved reference: builder` is the problem.

## Setup

As mentioned in https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1573, it should be possible to use Apollo Android without Android.

### Environment

I'm using Arch Linux and IntelliJ, with the JS GraphQL IntelliJ plugin installed.

#### Gradle Kotlin DSL build file

When writing the build file I already ran into a problem: I did not manage to avoid using the [deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application) `buildscript` block.

The plugin shown at https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.apollographql.apollo is apparently the incubating plugin as mentioned at https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1573#issuecomment-575613238 which is not yet ready.

The following build file seems to apply the plugin correctly:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.2.2")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "com.apollographql.android")

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.60"

    application
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    java
    idea  
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))

    // Apollo and dependencies
    implementation("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:1.2.2")

    implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

tasks.withType<com.apollographql.apollo.gradle.ApolloCodegenTask> {
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
}
```

so after syncing, I have the apollo Gradle tasks available.

### Downloading the schema

I installed the [Apollo cli interface](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/devtools/cli/) and then, following the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/#downloading-a-schema), I ran

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint=https://api.github.com/graphql --header="Authorization: Bearer mytoken"
```

which gave me a `schema.json` that I put in `src/main/graphql/nl/mypackage/myapplication/schema.json`.

### Example query

I have a file `src/main/graphql/nl/mypackage/myapplication/ViewLogin.graphql` which contains `query ViewLogin { viewer { login }}`.
IntelliJ shows an error on both `viewer` and `login`, saying `Unknown field "viewer" on object type "Query". Did you mean "viewer"?`. But this may be a misconfiguration of the JS GraphQL plugin.
I tried to configure JS GraphQL by adding a file `src/main/graphql/nl/mypackage/myapplication/.graphqlconfig` containing

```
{
  "name": "GitHub GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "schema.json",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/graphql",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the errors remain.

Then I executed the Gradle task `generateApolloClasses` which generated a `build/generated/source/apollo/classes/main/nl/mypackage/myapplication/ViewLoginQuery.kt` file.
When I open that file, no errors are shown and everything looks ok.

### Execute the query

In a file `src/main/kotlin/nl/mypackage/myapplication/GraphqlExample.kt` I tried to use the query, following the docs at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started/#consuming-code
but when I try to use `ViewLoginQuery.builder()` then `builder` is not recognized (by IntelliJ, and also when I try to run it).

I tried searching in superclasses of ViewLoginQuery but I couldn't find anything about a builder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where that `builder` is supposed to be, but you can instantiate the query directly and use that.

This is an example of consumer code (last tested with version 2.1.0):

```
import com.apollographql.apollo.ApolloCall
import com.apollographql.apollo.ApolloClient
import com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response
import com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloException
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val serverUrl = "https://api.github.com/graphql"

    val authHeader = args[0]

    // Add authentication header for GitHub
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
                builder.header("Authorization", "Bearer $authHeader")
                chain.proceed(builder.build())
            }
            .build()

    val apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
            .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
            .build()

    val query = ViewLoginQuery()

    apolloClient.query(query).enqueue(object : ApolloCall.Callback<ViewLoginQuery.Data?>() {
        override fun onResponse(dataResponse: Response<ViewLoginQuery.Data?>) {
            val data = dataResponse.data

            if (data == null) {
                println("No data received")
                println(dataResponse.errors)
            } else {
                println(dataResponse.data?.viewer?.login)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
            println(e.message)
        }
    })
}
```

To fix the 'unknown field' errors in the .graphql file, you have to download the schema as a `schema.graphql` instead of `schema.json`, see https://github.com/jimkyndemeyer/js-graphql-intellij-plugin/issues/305 for the issue report.
You also have to provide the github token in the header. Change your `.graphqlconfig` to the following:

```
{
  "name": "GitHub GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "./schema.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/graphql",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL",
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${env:GITHUB_GRAPHQL_TOKEN}"
        },
        "introspect": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can now easily download the new schema by clicking the 'run introspection query' gutter icon next to the `"url":` line.
You will get a popup asking for the token. Unfortunately the plugin does not yet support reading the environment variable from anywhere, see for example https://github.com/jimkyndemeyer/js-graphql-intellij-plugin/issues/285

However, Apollo Android requires a `schema.json`, so you need to keep the one you downloaded!
Since Apollo Android will (at least for me) error on the `schema.graphql` file, tell it to ignore that file by changing the Gradle task configuration to

```
apollo {
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
    graphqlSourceDirectorySet.srcDir("src/main/graphql")
    graphqlSourceDirectorySet.include("**/*.graphql")
    graphqlSourceDirectorySet.exclude("**/schema.graphql")
}
```

For documentation on those options, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/plugin-configuration/

To summarize: for the JS GraphQL plugin, which you want in order to easily work with graphql files, you need the `schema.graphql` which you download from the `.graphqlconfig`. For Apollo Android, you need the `schema.json`, which you download using the Apollo cli interface.

**[Edit June 2020] For Apollo Android 2, you can use the new Gradle plugin, so the complete build.gradle.kts becomes as follows:**

Remember to always check for dependency updates before using, for example using the help/useLatestVersions Gradle task from the use-latest-versions Gradle plugin.

```
plugins {

    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"

    application
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    java
    idea

    // Plugin which checks for dependency updates with help/dependencyUpdates task.
    id("com.github.ben-manes.versions") version "0.28.0"

    // Plugin which can update Gradle dependencies, use help/useLatestVersions
    id("se.patrikerdes.use-latest-versions") version "0.2.14"

    id("com.apollographql.apollo") version "2.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))

    // Apollo and dependencies
    implementation("com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.1.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:2.4.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:19.0.0")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:19.0.0")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

apollo {
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
    graphqlSourceDirectorySet.srcDir("src/main/graphql")
    graphqlSourceDirectorySet.include("**/*.graphql")
    graphqlSourceDirectorySet.exclude("**/schema.graphql")
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```